# Parsing URLs: removing a character from string

Tags: php

I am currently trying to format url links with `parse_url`. My goal is to parse the link every time it has the following characters `&p` (in that order)  in it. The `if statement` is there to check for these characters the in the `url` before deciding to parse the link or not. For example, if the link has the characters `&p` (in that order) then it will parse the link and format to my desired choice. I have been able to figure the parsing part but how would I be able to check for these characters `&p` (in that order)? If you see below example, I only want to remove `&` from the link.

```
if($url == '&p' ) // not sure how to check
{
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$fragment = $parsed_url['fragment'];
$fragment_parts = explode('/', $fragment);
$formatted_url = array_pop('http://www.website.com?p=$1',$url);
}
else    
{   
// do something else
}
```

**Example:**

Input: `http://www.website.com?&p=107`

Output: `'http://www.website.com?p=107`

Comment: Why don't you *always* parse the URL and reassemble it? If it was already properly formatted, it won't change, otherwise it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [str_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace this `&p` string with `p`.

```
$url = "http://www.website.com?&p=107";
$url = str_replace("&p", "p", $url);
echo $url; // will print http://www.website.com?p=107
```

[Test here](http://3v4l.org/dZHDp)

For more complex text processing you may use `preg_replace()`.

Comment: yes, but how can i check in the if statement if the string has the characters `&p` or not?

Comment: You can use `if(isnull(strpos($url, "&p")) {do something if not found}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check if the url has got the ?&p just use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
<?php
if(strpos($url, '?&p') !== false) {
//your magic
}
?>
```

Otherwise if you're trying to handle a bad request you can do something like:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // will have the /?&p=123
if(strpos($url, '?&p') !== false) {
    $url = str_replace("&p", "p", $url); // now you've only got ?p=123
    //then do what ever you like 
    //redirect to the appropriate URL or you can set the $_GET['p'] e.g.
    header("Location: /".$url);
    //or
    $parsed = parse_str($url, $get);
    $_GET['p'] = $get['?p'];
}
?>
```